# Do two coordinate systems cover the same patch of the de Sitter manifold

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am self studying general relativity and there is some especially hard problem (it is called bonus problem in book) I am currently working on it, but I am trully stuck, so I would appreaciate all the help I could get. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you solved (a)? Doesn’t (a*) depend on it?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without some information about where you got stuck. As it is, it's just a do-my-homework-for-me question, which is not allowed here.

Comment: I will provide additional information tommorow bcs it is pretty long